# Injecting options into form in Silex

Tags: forms, symfony, silex

I face a problem regarding form management in Silex.

I have a form (`RegionType`) that allows me to fill in and modify my domain (entities) information (example, information about a `Region` like name and description). This form extends `AbstractType` from Symfony.

I'm trying to inject a option into it (`validation_groups` to false) to be able to reuse the form to get data and use this data to make a search form my DB.

As the form for a search and the form for editing will use the same fields with same kind of data, I did not wanted to duplicate my classes.

Here is my `RegionType` form :

```
<?php

namespace Easytrip2\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class RegionType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add ( 'name', 'text', array (
                'label' => 'Region code'
        ) );
        $builder->add ( 'description', 'text', array (
                'label' => 'Region description'
        ) );
    }
    public function getName() {
        return 'region';
    }
    public static function getScriptsIdsArray() {
        return array (
                array ()
        );
    }
}
```

I can use it for my search just by duplicating it and adding the following method :

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults ( array (
            'validation_groups' => false
    ) );
}
```

My controller for editing the form in the Type version (standard Create Update thing) :

```
public function regionUpdateByIdAction($id, Request $request, Application $app) {
        if (/*check the user rights*/) {
            //find the object being updated
            $obj = $app ['dao.region']->findById ( $id );
            //create form and handle request
            $form = $app ['form.factory']->create ( new RegionType ( $app ), $obj );
            $form->handleRequest ( $request );
            if ($form->isSubmitted () && $form->isValid ()) {
                if ($app ['dao.region']->save ( $obj )) {
                    //warn user and redirect
                    $app ['session']->getFlashBag ()->add ( 'success', 'The region was succesfully updated.' );
                    return $app->redirect ( $app ['url_generator']->generate ( 'region' ) );
                } else {
                    $app ['session']->getFlashBag ()->add ( 'error', 'Something went wrong...' );
                }
            }
            //generate the form view
            return $app ['twig']->render ( 'form.html.twig', array (
                    'form' => $form->createView (),
                    'title' => 'Edit region'
            ) );
        } else {
            $app ['session']->getFlashBag ()->add ( 'error', 'Don\'t have the rights...' );
            return $app->redirect ( $app ['url_generator']->generate ( 'home' ) );
        }
    }
```

What i would like to do is use the following line

```
form = $app ['form.factory']->create ( new RegionType ( $app ), $obj );
```

and add a option in it allowing to pass an option, like

```
$form = $app ['form.factory']->create ( new RegionType ( $app ), $obj, array (
                    'validation_groups' => false
            ) );
```

When debugging, i find that my option gets down to the normalizers, and the `validation_groups` normalizer change it from `false` to an empty `array`, line 962 of `OptionsResolver.php`, with the following stacktrace (no error occur, just to show the call stack).

```
C:/path/to/app/Easytrip2/vendor/symfony/options-resolver/OptionsResolver.php.Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver->offsetGet(): lineno 944 
C:/path/to/app/Easytrip2/vendor/symfony/options-resolver/OptionsResolver.php.Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver->resolve(): lineno 791   
C:/path/to/app/Easytrip2/vendor/symfony/form/ResolvedFormType.php.Symfony\Component\Form\ResolvedFormType->createBuilder(): lineno 104  
C:/path/to/app/Easytrip2/vendor/symfony/form/Extension/DataCollector/Proxy/ResolvedTypeDataCollectorProxy.php.Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\DataCollector\Proxy\ResolvedTypeDataCollectorProxy->createBuilder(): lineno 83   
C:/path/to/app/Easytrip2/vendor/symfony/form/FormFactory.php.Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory->createNamedBuilder(): lineno 87    
C:/path/to/app/Easytrip2/vendor/symfony/form/FormFactory.php.Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory->createBuilder(): lineno 67 
C:/path/to/app/Easytrip2/vendor/symfony/form/FormFactory.php.Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory->create(): lineno 39    
C:/path/to/app/Easytrip2/src/Controller/RegionController.php.Easytrip2\Controller\RegionController->regionSearchAction(): lineno 39 
C:/path/to/app/Easytrip2/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php.call_user_func_array:{D:\users\F001780\Desktop\soft\wamp\www\Easytrip2\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php:139}(): lineno 139  
C:/path/to/app/Easytrip2/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php.Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(): lineno 139 
C:/path/to/app/Easytrip2/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php.Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(): lineno 62 
C:/path/to/app/Easytrip2/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Application.php.Silex\Application->handle(): lineno 586   
C:/path/to/app/Easytrip2/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Application.php.Silex\Application->run(): lineno 563  
C:/path/to/app/Easytrip2/web/index.php.{main}(): lineno 10
```

Could anybody explain this behavior ? I'm slightly lost here in the mecanics...

I forgot my composer.json settings :

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~1.3",
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.5.*",
        "symfony/security": "2.7.*",
        "twig/twig": "1.21.*",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "2.7.*",
        "symfony/form": "2.7.*",
        "symfony/translation": "2.7.*",
        "symfony/config": "2.7.*",
        "jasongrimes/silex-simpleuser": "*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.3.*",
        "symfony/validator": "2.*",
        "phpoffice/phpexcel": "1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bridge": "*",
        "box/spout": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "*",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "*",
        "silex/web-profiler": "*"
    },
    "autoload":{
        "psr-4":{"Easytrip2\\": "src"}
    },
    "autoload-dev":{
        "psr-4":{"Easytrip2\\": "tests"}
    }
}
```

Comment: Normalizer for validation_groups changes `false` to empty array. You can look how it wokrks in `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\Type\BaseValidatorExtension`

Comment: You can set `validation_groups` to null, it is default value

Comment: Both of you are right, and i took time to realize that empty array evaluates to false. But then i do not manage to understand what change this behavior and why the validation takes place...

Comment: Actually, i jsut realized that the validation does not takes place in the server, but only in browser. I mismatched the two. So i guess i'll just have to find a way to remove the browser "validation" (which is in my case just a `required` tag. I guess i could use one of the existing options for that. I'll keep you informed.

Comment: try to add `novalidate` attribute to form. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i made a mistake here...
Thanks to Max P., I found it.

Actually with this configuration, the server does not make any validation. In addition to `validation_groups` set to false (to disable server validation), i have to add `require` option set to false as well, to ensure no required tag is sent to the browser.

So replacing :

```
$form = $app ['form.factory']->create ( new RegionType ( $app ), $obj, array (
                'validation_groups' => false
        ) );
```

by :

```
$form = $app ['form.factory']->create ( new RegionType ( $app ), $obj, array (
                'validation_groups' => false,
                'required' => false
        ) );
```

does works both on browser and server side.

Thanks !